# I don't understand why the variable has to be cloned and not referenced

Tags: rust

I am reading *The Rust Programming Language*. In this code, I don't understand why it has to be `args[1].clone()` and why it can't be `&args[1]`:

```
use std::env;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let config = parse_config(&args);

    println!("Searching for {}", config.query);
    println!("In file {}", config.filename);

    let contents = fs::read_to_string(config.filename)
        .expect("Something went wrong reading the file");

    println!("With text:\n{}", contents);
}

struct Config {
    query: String,
    filename: String,
}

fn parse_config(args: &[String]) -> Config {
    let query = args[1].clone();
    let filename = args[2].clone();

    Config { query, filename }
}
```

The book explains it but I still don't understand. It says something about the struct taking ownership.

Is this the same as the code above? This is what the compiler said to do when I changed `args[1].clone` to `&args[1]`

```
fn parse_config(args: &[String]) -> Config {
    let query = &args[1];
    let filename = &args[2];

    Config { query: query.to_string(), filename: filename.to_string() }
}
```

Comment: What's your background in? In some languages, like Java, all objects are references and a type like `&String` doesn't exist. On the other hand, in C++, the compiler sometimes automatically calls special constructors to convert from `string&` to `string`, so it can be kind of obscure when a thing is a reference and when not. In Rust `&String` and `String` are different types, and you have to explicitly call a method such as `.clone()` to convert the reference to the owned type.

Comment: I believe what he doesn't understand is the concept of moving/transfering ownership vs copying memory. Maybe an answer that explained why he can't move directly from the `args` reference and how this affects the actual variable in `main` would be accepted. Unfortunately, I'm not confident enough with rust to answer it. I'd recommend reading [this article](https://depth-first.com/articles/2020/01/27/rust-ownership-by-example/) and [this other one](https://rufflewind.com/2017-02-15/rust-move-copy-borrow).

Answer (score 9):

Since you mentioned "struct taking ownership or something", I'm going to deviate a little from your question to clarify things a bit.

### A simplified overview of ownership

The way rust deal with memory safety without resorting to garbage collection is by using the concepts of [ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html) and [borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html). These concepts take time to internalize, but some aspects of it can be seen in simple examples:

```
struct Bike {
   brand: String;
   tire: f32;
}

impl Bike {
   fn ride_bike(&self) {
       println!("Goin' where the weather suits my clothes!")
   }
}

fn main() {
   // You are the owner of the bike
   let rafaels_bike = Bike { 
      brand: String::from("Bike Friday"), 
      tire: 28.0 
   }
   
   // You are giving your bike to me
   let eduardos_bike = rafaels_bike

   // Since you gave the bike to me, you cannot ride it anymore
   // rafaels_bike.ride_bike()    // It will give a borrow after move error, if uncommented

   // The bike is mine now, so I can ride it.
   eduardos_bike.ride_bike()
}
```

Rust does things this way because it needs to know when to clean up memory. To do so, it looks at the owner's scope: when the owner goes out of scope, it's time to clean up its resources. In this case the `Bike` struct allocates memory, so it needs to be cleaned up.

This concept of ownership permeates every operation in Rust, including struct and function declarations, expressions, etc. As a result, the way you declare functions can give information to the caller about what you want to do with the data.

```
// Immutable borrow: You're giving me permission to use your data (Bike), 
// but I can't change it
fn have_a_look(bike: &Bike) 

// Mutable borrow: You're giving me permission to modify your data (Bike)
fn install_modifications(bike: &mut Bike) 

// Moving operation: You're giving the bike away, you cannot use it anymore
// after you call the function
fn give_to_charity(bike: Bike)     // Bike is still available inside the function
```

This also applies to the struct declaration, if you're declaring an attribute without an `&` behind it, it's saying that it wants to own the data**, so the `Bike` struct is saying that it wants to own the brand `String` data. Well, the bike analogy kind of falls apart here, so let's get back to your question.

** There's a small inconsistency here that applies to values that implement the [Copy trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html). If a value implements a Copy trait, rust will copy it around everywhere it can, so you don't need to bother with putting an `&` before the type, as it happens for `f32` and lots of other basic types.

### The problem at hand

To understand why you can't do what you want to do (use `&args[1]` instead of `args[1].clone()`), we need to keep in mind the [rules of ownership in rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#ownership-rules):

1. Each value in Rust has a variable that’s called its owner.
2. There can only be one owner at a time.
3. When the owner goes out of scope, the value will be dropped.

With this is mind, let's look at the `parse_config` function if it was implemented the way you want to:

```
// The Config struct wants to own both the query and filename strings
struct Config {
    query: String,
    filename: String,
}

// You're saying that you want to look at the args data and nothing else
fn parse_config(args: &[String]) -> Config {
    let query = &args[1];
    let filename = &args[2];

    // Then you're trying to give it away to Config behind the caller's back
    // You broke the contract
    Config { query, filename }
}
```

Essentially, if this was allowed the `Strings` in `args` would have two owners, the `args` and the `config` variables breaking rule n° 2 of ownership.

Let's suppose rust wasn't so strict and rule n° 2 didn't exist. In this hypothesis, this would be possible:

```
// This is a world without rule n° 2, this code will not compile.
use std::env;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    // args own the String inside the Vec
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let contents = {
        // config will also own the Strings at index 1 and 2
        let config = parse_config(&args);

        println!("Searching for {}", config.query);
        println!("In file {}", config.filename);

        fs::read_to_string(config.filename)
            .expect("Something went wrong reading the file")

        // config goes out of scope, cleaning the memory for strings it owns
    };

    // The strings at index 1 and 2 don't exist anymore
    // This is known as a dangling pointer
    println!("{:?}", args);

    println!("With text:\n{}", contents);

    // End of scope: Will try to clean args memory, but some of it was already cleaned
    // This is known as a double-free
}

struct Config {
    query: String,
    filename: String,
}

fn parse_config(args: &[String]) -> Config {
    let query = &args[1];
    let filename = &args[2];
    
    // Give the strings to Config anyway
    Config { query, filename }
}
```

As you see, everything would break and Rust would not be able to guarantee memory safety anymore.

### The Solutions

#### Cloning

The solution the book offers is to [clone](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) the strings, meaning that you allocate an entire new block of memory thats different from the one `args` is owning:

```
    let query = args[1].clone();
    let filename = args[2].clone();
```

Now both `config` and `args` are ok, since they own entirely different blocks of memory. When they go out of scope, each one will clean what they are owning.

#### Moving into the function

This one was already mentioned. You can move the `args` variable in main to the function parameter. Since it now owns the data, you can do whatever you want with it, including giving ownership to another struct.

```
fn parse_config(mut args: Vec<String>) -> Config
```

This works because the `main` function doesn't use the `args` variable after the `parse_config` is called. You still can't use indexing though, because you cannot move out of an Index since it happens by means of an immutable borrow:

from the [Index trait documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html#required-methods):

```
fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &Self::Output
```

#### Using to_string()

This one you arrived yourself and yes, it's functionally equivalent to the one provided by the book.

The implementation of `to_string` for `String` is as following:

```
// to_string is implemented by means of to_owned
#[stable(feature = "string_to_string_specialization", since = "1.17.0")]
impl ToString for String {
    #[inline]
    fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        self.to_owned()
    }
}

// to_owned uses clone when the type implements the Clone trait
[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl<T> ToOwned for T
where
    T: Clone,
{
    type Owned = T;
    fn to_owned(&self) -> T {
        self.clone()
    }

    fn clone_into(&self, target: &mut T) {
        target.clone_from(self);
    }
}

// And String implements Clone
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl Clone for String {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        String { vec: self.vec.clone() }
    }

    fn clone_from(&mut self, source: &Self) {
        self.vec.clone_from(&source.vec);
    }
}
```

## Using lifetimes

You can also solve this by using lifetimes in the `Config` struct, like this:

```
struct Config<'a> {
    query: &'a String,
    filename: &'a String,
}

fn parse_config(args: &[String]) -> Config {
    let query = &args[1];
    let filename = &args[2];

    // Now config is not trying to own the Strings
    // So you can pass your references to it
    Config { query, filename }
}
```

This allows you to implement the code the way you want to but it ties the lifetime of the `Config` result to the lifetime of `args`, which in this case is the `main` function scope.

In other words, you can only access `config.filename` and `config.query` while the initial owner (`args` in `main`) is still in scope.

I've made a playground with an [working example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f26f036fcbaf7c79d04a8c4d208be533) and another with [a different scope for args](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d11f1b616986f4aa4b5f2919ea3d0f35) so you can see how the lifetime affects the return.

---

I'm not a Rust pro and I made some simplifications in order to make the explanation straightfoward. If I said anything wrong hopefully a more experienced rustacean will correct me.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::ops::Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) returns a reference to the type in the container, in this case a slice.

You have several options for getting working code. The best of them is to rewrite `parse_config` to take a `Vec`.

```
fn parse_config(mut args: Vec<String>) -> Config {
    let filename = args.remove(2);
    let query = args.remove(1);

    Config { query, filename }
}
```

Comment: I think `remove` will shift the contents of the vector so I think the second call will give you the 3rd argument... https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.remove

Comment: ... or assign the argument backwards with remove could also work...

Comment: You are right. It should either be both `remove(1)` or backwards as you suggested.